# PayPal API fall 2015: Peer to peer payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am working on a project trying to set up PayPal peer-to-peer payments. However, the adaptive payments API seems to be a very old version of the current PayPal API which was not renewed recently.

Is there anything I am missing or is this part of the API still working and in place? It seems like the whole structure is very different form what is usual when looking at the PayPal API.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adaptive Payment is just another platform that's available for specific things, mainly chained payments and preapproval profiles.

It is still widely used and is not going anywhere.  The REST API (which I guess you would consider the new one) is not nearly as mature as the Classic API, so you can do a lot more in Classic in general than you can in REST.

I still prefer Classic/Adaptive for everything, personally.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is currently a bit confusing.

On their "main" Adaptive Payment page, they explicitly mention "peer-to-peer" but I struggled to find this explained in any sub-section.

There is [another Adaptive Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/#ap) section in the documentation under NVP / SOAP API.
It's here that you can find the [Pay API Operation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/), which includes personal peer-to-peer transfers.